# Java Current Date Time not recognized by Sqlite DateTime

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, datetime-format

I am using the following code in Android to get current date time

```
Date currentDateTime = new Date();
```

And storing it in the sqlite table as

```
currentDateTime.ToString()
```

SO in the table the values are stored like so

```
"Tue Sep 11 20:32:39 IST 2012"
"Thu Sep 13 17:23:38 IST 2012"
"Thu Sep 13 17:34:38 IST 2012"
"Thu Sep 13 20:21:58 IST 2012"
```

Now I need to sort them in sqlite in desc order i.e.

```
select datetime(datecolumn) from table order by datetime(datecolumn) desc;
```

> But when I do datetime(column) on the field it shows me null for all the rows on the date field

Obviously there is a data mismatch on the sqlite side. But I am not sure how to fix it - Is there a way I can still change the query on the sqlite side to be able to read this? Or do I have to change the JAVA code and insert the data in a sqlite readable format.

I need the times also since I am dealing with hourly data.

Comment: When you said storing in sqlite table, are you using JDBC or its equivalent? If so, why aren't you using `setDate(<column>, new java.sql.Date(date.getMillis())` to insert the date field? If not JDBC, why not?

Comment: Sorry I should mention I am using JAVA Android sqlite insert helper, inserting data directly into the sqlite table

Comment: Always Keep datetime in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format if you were to add datetime from java code. If you just want to add current datetime to sqlite db use DateTime('Now','Localtime') from sqlite commandset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use

```
currentDateTime.getTime())
```

and store that value - less space needed in the database, and I assume much quicker to sort for sqlite

Answer (score 1):

See [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for the list of formats that are recognized as dates by SQLite.

If you want the database fields to be more readable than a single milliseconds value, format the strings as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.